# Internal and External communication in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Flow:
On-Prem ------>Proxy--->Kafka

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://proxyhostname:8080 - for external communication
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 = for internal communication
```

•When we set both the property, the internal communication is not happening.(Replication issue and the consumer couldn’t connect via locally and we have to provide the proxy Ip for consumer communication)

•How we can effectively use both the property for internal and external communication?

•Any alternative idea to do the external and internal communication?

Answer (score 3):

It's very common to define multiple listeners and Kafka supports that very well.

To define several listeners, you need to list all of them in `advertised.listeners`/`listeners`.

If multiple listeners are going to use the same Security Protocol (`PLAINTEXT`), you also need to set `listener.security.protocol.map` to map custom names to Security Protocols. See [broker configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) in the Kafka Docs.

For example:

```
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://proxyhostname:8080
listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:8080
```

This maps 2 names `EXTERNAL` and `INTERNAL` (you can use any name you like, I just reused names from your question) to the `PLAINTEXT` security protocol. Then for each, it defines the port to listen to and the hostname to advertise in metadata responses.

Comment: We are using Cloudera here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are using cloudera here.
When we add the below property,Kafka server is showing the error.
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://10.91.192.124:8080
2018-12-28 06:03:28,009 FATAL kafka.Kafka$:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://10.91.192.124:8080': No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.INTERNAL
       
Please assist.

Comment: What is the broker version? It looks like your version does not support this feature. This was added in Kafka 0.10.2 (released ~2 years ago), see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-103%3A+Separation+of+Internal+and+External+traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the information.we are using 0.10.0+kafka2.1.2.
Wiki link suggest that 0.10.2.0 and 0.11.0.0.
Please suggest which one we can go ahead.

Comment: You need at least 0.10.2 to use this feature. Pre 0.10.2, the only option you have is to use different security protocols for the 2 listeners (or upgrade to a recent version as 0.10.0 is now very old!)

Comment: Currently i cant upgrade the version. So I have added like this.(advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://proxyhost:8080). I have received the below exception from Kafka.[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners protocols must be equal to or a subset of listeners protocols. Found Set(PLAINTEXT, SSL). The valid options based on currently configured protocols are Set(PLAINTEXT)
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1032)
]

Comment: I got this error when i select the SSL,security.inter.broker.protocol can not be set to SSL, as SSL is not enabled on this Kafka broker.

Comment: We have upgraded the version to 0.10.2 and set the below property listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://proxyhostname:8080
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT://proxyHost,': No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT....Please assist

Comment: It looks like you have a config using `PLAINTEXT`, what have you set `security.inter.broker.protocol` to?

Comment: listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://proxyhost:8080
listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:8080
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
security.inter.broker.protocol=PLAINTEXT  2019-01-02 13:05:21,873 FATAL kafka.Kafka$:
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Only one of inter.broker.listener.name and security.inter.broker.protocol should be set.
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.getInterBrokerListenerNameAndSecurityProtocol(KafkaConfig.scala:1035)
        a

Comment: With the mapping you've defined, you have to set `security.inter.broker.protocol` to `INTERNAL` instead of `PLAINTEXT`.

Comment: Kafka configuration:
-----------------------------
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://proxyhost.124:8080
listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:8080
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
security.inter.broker.protocol=INTERNAL
error: 2019-01-03 03:32:45,436 FATAL kafka.Kafka$:
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Only one of inter.broker.listener.name and security.inter.broker.protocol should be set.at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.getInterBrokerListenerNameAndSecurityProtocol(KafkaConfig.scala:1035)