# Updating Kafka advertised.listeners using kafka-configs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I have to update Kafka broker config advertised.listeners using the command line tool "kafka-configs.sh". The reason for using the command line is because the instance/brokers are running in AWS and to access it from outside we need to add our endpoint to this.
Currently from the ZkCli, we can see the list of current listener endpoints:

```
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"CLIENT":"PLAINTEXT","CLIENT_SECURE":"SSL","REPLICATION":"PLAINTEXT","REPLICATION_SECURE":"SSL"},"endpoints":["CLIENT://b-1:9092","CLIENT_SECURE://b-1:9094","REPLICATION://b-1:9093","REPLICATION_SECURE://b-1:9095"],"rack":"subnet-09d8","jmx_port":9099,"host":"b-1.amazonaws.com","timestamp":"1574664497892","port":9092,"version":4}
```

When I try to add our listener security protocol for one of the brokers, we are getting the below error:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9094  --command-config client.properties --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 --alter --add-config  listener.security.protocol.map="EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException: Invalid config value for resource ConfigResource(type=BROKER, name='1'): Error creating broker listeners from 'CLIENT://b-1.amazonaws.com:9092,CLIENT_SECURE://b-1.amazonaws.com:9094,REPLICATION://b-1amazonaws.com:9093,REPLICATION_SECURE://b-1.amazonaws.com:9095': No security protocol defined for listener CLIENT
```

If we try to add our endpoint directly, we are getting:

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9094  --command-config client.properties --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 --alter --add-config advertised.listeners="PLAINTEXT://vpce-amazonaws.com:36379"
: No security protocol defined for listener PLAINTEXT
```

To verify if we can do this, we tried adding some other parameter and looks like it is working as expected:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9094  --command-config client.properties --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 --alter --add-config log.cleaner.threads=2
Completed updating config for broker: 1.
```

Looked here and there, tried specifying all security groups(with our addition) but no luck.What are we missing here?

Comment: We are trying to follow this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945143/internal-and-external-communication-in-kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the correct way was:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9094    
  --command-config client.properties    
 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1     
 --alter --add-config listener.security.protocol.map=["CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT_SECURE:SSL,REPLICATION:PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION_SECURE:SSL"]
```

Answer (score 0):

On your command you only define one map:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9094  
--command-config  client.properties 
--entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 
--alter --add-config  listener.security.protocol.map="EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
```

You should try to add the full list:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9094  
--command-config  client.properties 
--entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 
--alter --add-config  listener.security.protocol.map="EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT_SECURE:SSL,REPLICATION:PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION_SECURE:SSL"
```

Comment: @Issilva Thanks for your time but getting `failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val" `, also trying with {} like `{"EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT","CLIENT:PLAINTEXT","CLIENT_SECURE:SSL","REPLICATION:PLAINTEXT","REPLICATION_SECURE:SSL"}` then the error is:`No security protocol defined for listener CLIENT` Tried other combinations like:```"EXTERNAL=PLAINTEXT","CLIENT=PLAINTEXT","CLIENT_SECURE=SSL","REPLICATION=PLAINTEXT","REPLICATION_SECURE=SSL"
requirement failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val" ``` and with {}.

Comment: @Rahul try without all the extra quotes

Comment: @cricket_007 `"EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT_SECURE:SSL,REPLICATION:PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION_SECURE:SSL"
requirement failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val" ` and even this is same `"EXTERNAL=PLAINTEXT,CLIENT=PLAINTEXT,CLIENT_SECURE=SSL,REPLICATION=PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION_SECURE=SSL"
requirement failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val". `